# How to create table graphic in R that includes pch-style symbols within table cells?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I am working on making some plots with ggplot2 that I am exporting to use in a report. I now want to create interpretive tables to go along with the plots. I would like the tables to look almost like a legend for the plots, with one column of the table showing the color/symbol from the plot and additional columns containing descriptive information.

Here's an example: suppose that I have these two related plots:
[image]
[image]

Now, I have a (desired) table which looks like this, theoretically:
[image]

But, the `Symbol` column would show a yellow circle, red circle, and red triangle, corresponding to the display on the plots.

I am struggling to find a way to dynamically generate such a table. Normally for nice looking tables I use the `knitr::kable` function. It has a lot of nice visual features (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html) but I still can't figure out how to add symbols that match up with the pch symbols allowed by R/ggplot2.

Hoping for any suggestions to point me in the right direction. A package I should be using? A feature of kable I wasn't aware of? A way to represent R pch symbols in a character variable so that i can send them through to my tables? Other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

data.frame(
  Symbol = c("&#9679;", "&#9679;", "&#9650;"),
  Description = c("bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla"),
  Result = c("bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla")
) %>%
  mutate(
    Symbol = cell_spec(Symbol, color = c("yellow", "pink", "pink"), escape = F)
  ) %>%
  kable(escape = F, align = c("c", "l", "l")) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)
```

gives you
[image]

You can use https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp for symbol references

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you kindly.